# Uncaught ReferenceError: cartRowContents is not defined

Tags: javascript

#### CODE

Here's the code for a function which is triggered when a person clicks on "Add to Cart" button. It creates a row inside the cart using the data from localStorage about the items selected by the user from the menu.

```
function addItemToCart() {
  var cartRow = document.createElement("div");
  cartRow.classList.add("cart-row");
  var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-items")[0];
  var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName("cart-item-title");
  //Putting the data
  var locStore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedProduct"));
  locStore.forEach((item) => {
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${item.image}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${item.title}</span>
            <span class="cart-item-size">"Rs.${item.sizePrice}"</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${item.price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`;
  });

  cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents;
  cartItems.append(cartRow);
  cartRow
    .getElementsByClassName("btn-danger")[0]
    .addEventListener("click", removeCartItem);
  cartRow
    .getElementsByClassName("cart-quantity-input")[0]
    .addEventListener("change", quantityChanged);
}
```

#### ERROR

I'm getting the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cartRowContents is not defined
```

I have defined `cartRowContents`. I also tried defining it using `'let'` but the error persisted. 
I'm fetching the data from localStorage and rendering it to the UI using above method.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```js
locStore.forEach((item) => {
    var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${item.image}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${item.title}</span>
            <span class="cart-item-size">"Rs.${item.sizePrice}"</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${item.price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`;
  });
```

With

```js
var cartRowContents = locStore.map((item) => {
    return `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${item.image}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${item.title}</span>
            <span class="cart-item-size">"Rs.${item.sizePrice}"</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${item.price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`;
  });
```

Then you have an array with all the HTML, which you can join with this line:
`cartRowContents = cartRowContents.join("");`

The problem is the scope: You are defining cartRowContents only in that arrow function within forEach, and it can only be called inside there

Answer (score 1):

`cartRowContents` is declared inside a function, so it only "lives" inside the callback function of the `forEach`.

```js
[1, 2, 3].forEach(() => {
  var functionVariable = "I'm alive!";
});
console.log(functionVariable);
```

On the contrary, the following would work using a for loop (though not a good algorithm):

```js
for (value in [1, 2, 3]) {
  var loopVariable = "I'm alive!";
}
console.log(loopVariable);
```

Using a variable outside the block where it was declared is not a good idea. Instead, you could declare the variable before the `forEach`, assign it inside the `forEach` and then use it after checking it has a value.

```js
var loopVariable;
for (value in [1, 2, 3]) {
  loopVariable = "I'm alive!";
}
if (loopVariable) {
  console.log(loopVariable);
}
```

However, that doesn't look right yet because you are declaring a variable in each loop iteration. Do you really need to loop over `locStore`? Perhaps your intention was collecting an array of all the values, in which case you could do the following:

```
const cartRowContents = locStore.map((item) => {
  return `
    <div class="cart-item cart-column">
        <img class="cart-item-image" src="${item.image}" width="100" height="100">
        <span class="cart-item-title">${item.title}</span>
        <span class="cart-item-size">"Rs.${item.sizePrice}"</span>
    </div>
    <span class="cart-price cart-column">${item.price}</span>
    <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
        <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
    </div>`;
});
```

In this case, `cartRowContents` will be an array where each element will be the value assigned by each item in `locStore`.

Comment: The `=` after return is not needed btw

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you are trying to do within the `forEach` but the error is occurring because `cartRowContents` is defined within the scope of the callback parameter of `forEach`. It is not accessible by the outer scope, you should move it outside.

Comment: Within the forEach, I'm getting each object one by one from the localStorage. Each object contains something like it's title, price, sizePrice, image etc.

Comment: I want to display each object in one row inside the Cart. That is why I have initialized cartRowContents inside forEach. Each object will be shown in one row

Comment: okay, but what the forEach does in your code right now is just recreate the variable each time and assign a value to it, which then you cannot use in the outer scope. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66944304/8726012 is what you are actually looking for.